# Cannot access protected property MY_Loader::$_ci_cached_vars and extract cached variables

Tags: php, codeigniter

After an upgrade of Codeigniter I get this message:

> Cannot access protected property MY_Loader::$_ci_cached_vars

I know that this property is now protected so what can I do here?

```
extract($CI->load->_ci_cached_vars); // extract cached variables
```

I don't know how to use the `get_var` method now, because the property is protected

this is `get_var` method

```
/**
     * Get Variable
     *
     * Check if a variable is set and retrieve it.
     *
     * @param   array
     * @return  void
     */
    public function get_var($key)
    {
        return isset($this->_ci_cached_vars[$key]) ? $this->_ci_cached_vars[$key] : NULL;
    }
```

How to refactor this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   extract($CI->load->get_var($key));
```